# Kazhdan's property (T) vs residual finiteness

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, c-star-algebras, geometric-group-theory

There is a theorem that states that a discrete group $G$ with Kazhdan's Property $(T)$ **and** Property $(F)$ (so called *factorisation property*) is residually finite (see *Kirchberg, Discrete groups with Kazhdan' s property T and factorization property are residually finite*), i.e.

**Kazhdan's Property $(T)$ + Property F $\Rightarrow$ residual finite**.

For the definitions of Kazhdan's Property $(T)$ and residually finite see e.g. the corresponding wiki-articles.

> I am wondering if some kind of "converse" is true. More precisely, I am looking for some property, let us call it *Property X*, such that:
>
> **Residual finite + Property X $\Rightarrow$ Kazhdan's Property $(T)$**.

Maybe there is something similar in the literature?

**EDIT:** Definition for Property $F$ of the cited paper.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should also state the factorization property;  the other two are well known.

Comment: I think this problem would be easier if you required $G$ to be finitely presentable (does Property F imply this?). This is because there is a version of Rips construction, due to Olliver and Wise: for every finitely presented $Q$ there exists a finitely generated (but not finitely presentable), residually finite group $N$ with Property $T$, some (hyperbolic) group $H$, and a short exact sequence $1\rightarrow N\rightarrow H\rightarrow Q\rightarrow 1$. This sequence allows you to prove that $N$ can have certain pathological properties.

Comment: (An easy property is insoluble membership problem in $H$, by taking $Q$ to have insoluble membership problem. But this is a property of the embedding, not of the group.)

Comment: @user1729. This sounds interesting. Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: I also thought of Zuk's criterion for Property (T) to "forge" a property which does the job together with residual finiteness. But I have not done this in detail.

Comment: I've made a mistake. Sorry. I actually don't know if the kernel $N$ is residually finite. It *might* be (but skimming the Ollivier's and Wise's paper, probably not). But for reference: the original construction is: *Rips, E.* "Subgroups of small cancellation groups." *Bulletin Lond. Math. Soc.* 14.1 (1982): 45-47. Reference for the property T part: *Ollivier, Y., and Daniel W.* "Kazhdan groups with infinite outer automorphism group." *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* 359.5 (2007): 1959-1976.

Comment: (My error was because in Rips construction the group $H$ is $C^{\prime}(1/6)$, so acts properly and cocompactly on a non-positively curved cubical complex, and virtually on a special cubical complex. Therefore is residually finite but contains no subgroups with Property T. For a more general discussion on Rips construction: [here there be dragons](https://berstein.wordpress.com/2011/02/27/the-rips-construction-i/))

Comment: I am very skeptical that there is a meaningful Property X. I suggest, however, to ask this question on Mathoverflow.

Comment: @studiosus. I have done so, (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/239723/kazhdans-property-t-vs-residual-finiteness)